# How to call C functions from java, and calling Java functions from C in a single flow

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse, java-native-interface

I have 3 files

1. `Source.java`
2. `IntermediateC.c`
3. `Destination.java`

   a. (Java -> c) I am able to call c (Intermediate.c) functions from Java(Source.java)

   b. (c -> Java) I am able to call Java(Source.java) function  from c (Intermediate.c).

But i need to call `java(Source.java) --> c (Intermediate.c) --> Java(Destination.java)` in a single flow.

is it possible?

Comment: Did you try it?  I'm not familiar with JNI, but I don't see any reason why this wouldn't just work.

Comment: I cannot think of how/why would you call java functions from c? I really doubt it's the right solution for whatever problem you have.

Comment: Use [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) and pass a `Destination` callback to `Intermediate` from `Source`. **Note** You could also do this with JNI.

Comment: As i mentioned from Source to intermediate ,intermediate to Destination separately we can achieve by using JNI, but i need a single flow source to intermediate ,intermediate internally it should call Destination.

Comment: _"I am able to call Java(Source.java) function from c (Intermediate.c)."_ Based on that, it's unclear why you're not able to make calls into Destination.java as well. Please add more details to clarify exactly what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Post your code.  And read the answers here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210115/how-to-call-c-functionality-from-java?rq=1

Comment: There is a simple answer to your question: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: My problem is, i  have to call C  functions from java(Source.java),internally That C function should call Java function(Destination.java). in a single flow.